# Define Gesture in ES File Explorer

Tags: es-file-explorer, gesture-typing

I'm using ES File Explorer. There's one thing I want to ask, what is the purpose of the small spot at the center of the screen when I turn on the app?

Whenever I click on it, a toast message show

> No gesture defined. Please add or disable gestures in fast access

I've searched the web for the answer but there's no answer. Could anyone explain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gesture feature is explained on its [official manual](http://www.estrongs.com/eshelp/en/local.htm) (scroll down to **Gesture**), albeit slightly outdated.

> What is the purpose of the small spot at the center of the screen when I turn on the app?

The small spot (or the "gesture water drop", as it's officially called) is the trigger to start gesture action.

As hinted by the error message, you have to add a new gesture for this feature to work as supposed to be:

1. Open **Fast Access** (the drawer on the left side) by tapping the "three horizontal bars" or by sliding a finger from the left side of the screen to right.
2. Open **Tools**, there should be a **Gesture** with on/off button. From here, you can disable/enable the feature. Disabling the feature will remove the water drop.
3. Tap **Gesture**.
4. Select **Add a gesture**.
5. Choose the action you want to do.
6. Draw the gesture on the middle of the dialog
7. A new gesture will be added. You can also delete/edit the gesture.

   - Red dot is the starting point (i.e. gesture water drop)
   - Light blue line is the gesture path

Now that you have gestures defined, you can use it on the app:

1. Go back to main screen
2. Draw the gesture starting from "gesture water drop", following the path you've defined.